# Does the number of tables on a Redshift database affect performance

Tags: database-design, amazon-redshift

Beyond the total size of my data, does it make a difference if I keep the data in a large number of tables or consolidate into one large table?  Do tiny tables with almost no data have an effect on performance?

Answer (score 0):

As with any database, running a query on a table with more data will be slower due to the need to process the data. This is especially the case with Amazon Redshift since it does not use indexes -- rather, it reads through all the data (but can be made faster by using a `SORTKEY` which helps speed `WHERE` clauses).

Some Amazon Redshift users keep data in separate tables, such as one table per month. They then create a `VIEW` that combines 12 monthly tables together. This way, a query can be run on only the current month's table (which would be faster), or across 12 months of data.

A table (big or small) will not impact a query in which it is not involved.